# Different Likert scales used in statistical anlysis

Tags: likert, scales

I am using different Likert Scales in questionnaire. Three dependent variables have Likert scales of 4 points, 2 points and 2 points. Three independent variables have 3 points scales. One moderating variable has 3 points Likert Scale whereas the other moderating variable has three questions with 4 points, 3 points and 3 points scales. If I use average of each variable in statistical analysis to find correlation, regression and moderated regression, is it allowed and results are considered valid or not?

Comment: This question is answered here before see e.g., http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29824/factor-analysis-and-regression or http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/33865/regression-analysis-with-factor-scores-as-explanatory-variable

Comment: In fact, +1 for the clarity and usefulness of that additional context; sorry if this makes for conflicting feedback from me.